# Reveal more sub-categories on click using jQuery or other possible methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

The Magento store that I am currently working on has some Categories with too many sub-categories which is almost occupies half of the page and I don't want the customers to go to next page or wait for the entire page to load to get to list of next sub-categories. So I want to implement a method that shows **Load more button** when it has more then 11 sub categories and **reveal** other sub categories when clicked on **Load more button**. Once it has reach to the **end of the sub-categories list** I want to automatically hide **Load more button** and replace it with **Load less button** that should hide rest of the categories and display only 11 sub categories with **Load more button**.

I did tried some of the methods mentioned in other forums and tutorial websites but it didn't work for me and it messed up the website. I have attached a screenshot of the current layout that I have prepared which I will be using.

[image]

Update: Template code included

```
<div class="row categories-nav">
    <?php if(count($this->getCurrentChildCategories()) > 0): ?>
     <?php $subCategories = array(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            <?php
                //arrange by Letter
                foreach($_category->getChildren() as $_sub){
                    $letter = substr(strtolower($_sub->getName()),0,1);
                    $subCategories[$letter][0]['name'] = $letter; //0 index is the letter
                    $i = 1;
                    while(isset($subCategories[$letter][$i])){
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $subCategories[$letter][$i]['name'] = $_sub->getName();
                    $subCategories[$letter][$i]['url'] = $this->getCategoryUrl($_sub);
                }
            ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php
            $subCategories = array();
            //arrange by Letter
            $i = 0;
            foreach($this->getCurrentChildCategories() as $_sub){
                $subCategories[$i]['name'] = $letter; //0 index is the letter
                $subCategories[$i]['name'] = $_sub->getName();
                $subCategories[$i]['url'] = $this->getCategoryUrl($_sub);
                $i++;
            }
            //get a count of all elements for splitting
            echo '<h2>Sub Categories</h2>';
            echo '<div class="col-md-12">';             
            echo '<h3>Search By Categories</h3>';
            echo '<div class="sub-categories">';
            $i = 0;
            $mod = '#f6f6f6';
            foreach($subCategories as $sub){
                if($i != 0 && $i % 11 == 0){
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<span class="pull-right btn"><a href="#">Load more</a></span>';
                    echo '<div class="acc_container">';                 
                    echo '<div class="sub-categories sec block">';
                }
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="'.$sub['url'].'">' . $sub['name'] . '</a></button>';
                $i++;
            }
            //how far are we from getting a complete row?
            if($i % 12 != 0){
                //we are not at a complete row
                while($i % 10 != 0){
                    echo '';
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tnx, ok, personally I would add class "hide" (as I can see it's using bootstrap(?)) to categories in loop (that is triggered after 11th element) so to generate them in HTML but not show them 
and dynamically add 12th element (show/load more "button") that will have Prototype event listener "on click" and a simple function to "toggle" hidden divs).

If there are hundreds of categories I would "slice" them in whole DIVs (of twelwe) and do the same as above (hide (and show) classes and JS toggling but with a loop over all 12 elements).

And if there would still be some page loading issues I would write a "pagination" for these categories - a PHP function/class with pagination functionality - having "category", "offset", "start" as parameters - and then Prototype as AJAX call (triggered by button click).

I am not very Prototype guy but I'm sure you can find many examples here or all over the net...

This, last method is kind of bad for seo I think.

Also it opens another question (as all above does) - can (do we want it to) user bookmark (or spider find) exact subcategories list? If yes it means additional work and handling (as all AJAX app do)...

Maybe, just maybe, all these subcategories can be solved in an AI/UX way? So to speak - have less of them at same time :)?

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with Magento but as I know it uses Prototype (out-of-box).

So I would find whole generated sub-categories list (I suppose it is ...) and manipulate it via JS (Prototype).

It's hard to give accurate answers but as a concept I would look into template that is responsible for this list and "enrich" list with some unique IDs and classes, so I would be able to write Prototype logic for handling visibility etc.

Comment: you are right, Magento uses Prototype. I have included template code in my question for your reference.